# Filter unique values based on secondary attribute

Tags: google-sheets

I've filtered unique values (discarding blanks) from one sheet to another. I'd now like to add the equivalent of an 'if' to display unique values that also have a value attached to it.

To illustrate my point I've highlighted the values (green) of the values I'd like to carry through.

My current formula:

=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet2'!A1:A33,'Sheet2'!A1:A33<>""))

The working sheet(s) can be found here. I figured it's be easier than describing it in text.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1svoiYRZA0VP76HEjWYmJWd_j57Qf5HOHXNDlnpjfkqM/edit?usp=sharing

The formula in question is in cell A1 on Sheet1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put all the relevant information into the question; not as a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that condition in your filter function.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!A1:A33,Sheet2!A1:A33<>"", Sheet2!B1:B33>0))
```

If you want to return name AND value, try

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!A1:B33,Sheet2!A1:A33<>"", Sheet2!B1:B33>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

=FILTER(Sheet2!A:G,Sheet2!A:A=UNIQUE(Sheet2!A:A))

for my case,
unique column A,
bring along value B to G.